# A reference for studying spinors from a mathematical point of view

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I need to know spinors in terms of mathematics. Does anybody know a good reference for that purpose? I am familiar with spinor algebra but its mathematical perspective still is not clear to me.

Comment: https://youtu.be/SBdW978Ii_E

Answer (score 3):

Lawson and Michelsohn, [Spin Geometry](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/4573.html), is perhaps the standard mathematical reference, and an excellent book.

Answer (score 2):

As Ben McKay already mentioned, *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn is a great reference.

I want to add a few other references (in no particular order) that all include an introduction to the basic concepts of spin geometry (Clifford algebras and their representations, spin groups, spin structures, spinor bundles).

- *Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry* by Thomas Friedrich
- *Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic methods* by John Roe
- *A Spinorial Approach to Riemannian and Conformal Geometry* by J.-P. Bourguignon, O. Hijazi, J.-L. Milhorat, A. Moroianu, S. Moroianu. This is a fairly recent book.
- *Spectral Properties of the Dirac Operator and Geometrical Structures* by O. Hijazi. This appeared in Proceedings of the Summer School on Geometric Methods in Quantum Field Theory, Villa de Leyva, Colombia, July 12-30, (1999), World Scientific 2001
- *The Dirac Spectrum* by N. Ginoux.